# Resuming play of live video stream after AVPlayerItemFailedToPlayToEndTime

Tags: ios, avplayer, http-live-streaming

If some error happens on the server side (playlist) of HLS, the `AVPlayer` client will eventually stop and we will get this notification: `AVPlayerItemFailedToPlayToEndTime`.

How can we resume play after this, taking for granted that all errors serverside are fixed?

- I cause 500 errors on the playlist side. The AVPlayer stops after a while.
- Even after AVPlayerItemFailedToPlayToEndTime has happened, the status of the AVPlayer is NOT `failed`, and the currentItem.status is also NOT `failed`. Specifically both of these are still `readyToPlay` which looks like we SHOULD be able to continue playing without recreating the whole AVPlayer instance etc.
- The way I try to cause a "play" again is `self.play()` (subclass of AVPlayer). This does not work.
- I've been able to resume play (from a failed state) by recreating the AVPlayerItem and assigning it again using `replaceCurrentItem()`. However since I need this to happen without any user interaction (like pressing play button etc), it seems like there is no good way to find out WHEN to apply this method, and if it really worked or not.

Comment: Keep track of time of media playing, in case of server failure replay media again forwarding to that time.

Comment: Just maybe related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19438095/avplayer-how-to-handle-network-interruptions

Comment: yes make timeCount Var class level and  increament it by one using method   periodic call as in link. So now time will be saved in your variable, use it to in seek time of avplayer.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19142835/1242673

Comment: I don't see how that is related at all. Anyway, it seems that AVPlayer's behavior is to stop trying to download anymore segments after it has failed to a certain extent from server errors (500s). It also seems like we have to recreate the AVPlayerItem again to be able to try again. Also WHEN to do that seems a highly related but different, and problematic issue. I need to find out when playback has stalled indefinitely and find some kind of timing when to do retries. I would assume AVPlayer does this for us, but it seems to gives up all attempts at some point. 

Comment: Steps what i meant about tracking time: MediaPlaying -> In mean time player is failed, save playing time when it fails -> recreate  playeritem -> Play again with seek time to saved time.

Comment: Ok I guess that is important for playing VOD, whereas I am playing live streams, I don't worry that much about at what time the user was watching, it will always change because it's a live playlist. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to save your pause time. Whenever you have yo play video again, say 'Play Button Click' OR 'Resume Video' , seek to that time

```
avPlayer.seek(to: playerPauseTime)

if self.avPlayer.status == .readyToPlay && self.avPlayer.currentItem?.status == .readyToPlay {

        self.avPlayer.seek(to: atTime,
                           toleranceBefore: kCMTimeZero,
                           toleranceAfter: kCMTimeZero,
                           completionHandler: { (finished) in

                            self.avPlayer.play()
        })
    }
```

And you will be playing your video from time lapse where it was paused.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by pause time, the user cannot deliberately pause. Also, this is a live stream so I'm not sure seeking has any meaning.

Comment: FWIW, I tried this out temporarily: always resuming using a seek to "zero" time. However the seek call never finishes if the avplayer is in a "bad" state after 500 errors happened on the playlist side.